# php drop down menu with main categories and child with sub child categories with heirarchical database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a drop down menu on first it shows main categories then all child categories with all of their sub child list like the one shown in below pic [desired drop down menu](http://s30.postimg.org/mngh68egx/temp.png)

I am using a readymade hiearchical database. my databse structure is like [my database structure](http://s1.postimg.org/usixo0bkv/temp1.png)

here is my false approach categoriesTest.php

```
<?php
include 'common.php';
$query = "SELECT cat_id, parent_id, cat_name FROM " .$DBPrefix. "categories ORDER BY cat_name";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
$items = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$html = '';
$parent = 0;
$parent_stack = array();

// $items contains the results of the SQL query
$children = array();
foreach ( $items as $item )
    $children[$items['parent_id']][] = $item;

while  ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) 
{
    if ( !empty( $option ) )
    {
        // 1) The item contains children:
        // store current parent in the stack, and update current parent
        if ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['id']] ) )
        {
            $html .= '<li>' . $option['value']['title'] . '</li>';
            $html .= '<ul>'; 
            array_push( $parent_stack, $parent );
            $parent = $option['value']['id'];
        }
        // 2) The item does not contain children
        else
            $html .= '<li>' . $option['value']['title'] . '</li>';
    }
    // 3) Current parent has no more children:
    // jump back to the previous menu level
    else
    {
        $html .= '</ul>';
        $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );
    }
}

// At this point, the HTML is already built
echo $html;

?>
```

the above code does not do the job.
I am quiet newbie and cant figure out.
tried all stacked questions but no success
can anyone suggest me the correct php code?